# How to make an input box to accept positive and negative decimal values?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, inputbox

How can I make an input box to accept only one `-` sign OR one `+` sign AND one decimal point with numbers?

I tried `preventDefault(); to block other characters by following code:

```
$('.pndecimal').on('keypress keyup blur', function(e){
         if(e.which< 48 && e.which > 57)
         { 
            e.preventDefault();
         }
    });
```

I'm not able to allow these because they are out of range of ASCII codes of numbers (e.which<48 & e.which >57)

Comment: Well i didn't actually understand why but instead of using an input maybe just use a `<select>` with options that you need ? :)

Comment: My requirement is to record optical signal which ranges from -50.00 to +3.00

Comment: Aight then maybe use input  type number with range -50 to +3 and step 1? Would this work for you?

Comment: `<input type="number" min=-50 max=3 step=0.1 />` something like this is already limiting every thing you need i'm guessing

Comment: min and max are not supported by all browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expression validation, if it passes take the value or else show error.

eg: `/(-|\\+)+[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+/g`

valid inputs: +9.0, -9.7, +78.9, -10.0

If you want to have more than one number after decimal point than use this pattern(this patterns also allow inputs like -99/,++,--)

eg:  `/(-|\\+)+[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+/g`

valid inputs: +91.42, +1.809, -9.0

If you want to restrict to 2 integer numbers,2 decimal numbers,any one sign use the following:

`RegExp(/(-|\+)+[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/g)`

`<input type="text" maxlength="4">`

Comment: can you please mention the correct usage of regexp ? inorder to make it for a special class like `.pndecimal`

Comment: RESULT GIVES ME ONLY -2.8... Why 9 is avoided?  `var pat= /[-+]\d*.[0-9]/g;
    var txt= "-2.89";
    var result = txt.match(pat);`

Comment: var pat = /(-|\+)+\d*.[0-9]/g; updated pattern, try with this

pat.test(txt);

examples: 

pat.test('+91.2'); // output: true.

pat.test('90.7'); // output: false

pat.test('18'); // output: false

pat.test('-21.2'); // output: true.

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_regexp_test2

note: replace pattern and txt and check in above website

Comment: if you want to have more than one numbers after decimal point then Use this pattern /(-|\+)+\d*.[0-9]+/g

Comment: $('.pndecimal').on('keypress keyup blur', function(e){
var pat= new RegExp(/(-|\+)+\d*.[0-9]+/g);     var txt= "-2.89";     var result = pat.test(txt);
         if(result) {
              // pattern matches, proceed further
} else {
 $('.error').text('Error, follow this pattern eg: '+96.8' or '-9.5');
}
    });

note: i would use only blur event, so it doesnt call on every keypress

i hope you can move forward from here

Comment: Thanks Bro..! Its ok to use blur only... thanks for the idea

Comment: Glad it solved your task and thanks for giving me my first green tick mark :)

Comment: Well, it just served my need... but it has many little problems..

Comment: actually i required a input box that serves to accept +ve and -ve decimal numbers, which should not allow +,-,. signs more than once (which works on keypress keyup events). Anyway this idea made my data to be validated somehow... THANKS FOR THAT HELP

Comment: im using jQuery 3.4.1

Comment: I have updaed regex, please use it
/(-|\+)+[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/g

Comment: If you face regex issue again in future, post a comment, will look into it